# Parsing Json in variable in golang

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

how do I parse this json

```
[
  [
    [
      "Odio los lunes",
      "i hate mondays",
      null,
      null,
      1
    ]
  ],
  null,
  "en"
]
```

to show just `Odio los lunes`?

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/bFZO6P1aoP9

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Implement `unmarshalar` to fetch the value required from nested array and parse it into and struct using `unmarshal` like:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

func(item *Result) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte)error{
    var v []interface{}
    if err:= json.Unmarshal(data, &v);err!=nil{
        fmt.Println(err)
        return err
    }
    item.Data = v[0].(interface{}).([]interface{})[0].([]interface{})[0].(string)
    return nil
}

type Result struct {
    Data string
}

func main() {
    var result Result
    jsonString := []byte(`[[["Odio los lunes", "i hate mondays", null, null, 1]], null, "en"]`)
    if err := json.Unmarshal(jsonString, &result); err != nil{
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    //fmt.Printf("%+v\n",result)
    value := result.Data
    fmt.Println(value)
}
```

[Playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/UfjsvHBKik_u)

Comment: how to get only the text, without the struct? Like just `Odio los lunes`

Comment: Please check edited answer and link to playground example

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach would be to parse the JSON document as an `interface{}` ("any type") and grab the target string value by asserting the parsed structure.  For example [(on the go playground)](https://play.golang.org/p/JluyaPClblX):

```
func main() {
  str := GetTargetString([]byte(jsonstr))
  fmt.Println(str) // => "Odio los lunes"
}

func GetTargetString(bs []byte) string {
  var doc interface{}
  if err := json.Unmarshal(bs, &doc); err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
  return doc.([]interface{})[0].([]interface{})[0].([]interface{})[0].(string)
}
```

The "GetTargetString" function will panic if the given byte slice does not contain a valid JSON document or if the structure of the document isn't adequately similar (that is, an array whose first element is an array, whose first element is an array, whose first element is a string).

A more idiomatic (and generally safer) approach would be to inspect the types using the special two-return-value form of the type assertion and return a tuple of `(string, error)`, e.g.:

```
if err := json.Unmarshal(jsonString, &result); err != nil {
  return "", err
}

array0, ok := doc.([]interface{})
if !ok {
  return "", fmt.Errorf("JSON document is not an array")
}

array1, ok := array0[0].([]interface{})
if !ok {
  return "", fmt.Errorf("first element is not an array")
}

// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It is much simpler (and faster) with [fastjson](https://github.com/valyala/fastjson):

```
var p fastjson.Parser
v, err := p.Parse(input)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Printf("v[0][0][0]: %s", v.GetStringBytes("0", "0", "0"))
```